# How to access PSI structure for both Java, Python in a single Intellij Plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, pycharm, gradle-plugin, intellij-plugin

I am developing a plugin for Pycharm, Intellij IDEA. Need to access PSI features (PSIMethod(java class) & PyFunction) for Java and Python language in both the IDEs versions (2022.3.1 and above)
Unable to write a common plugin which can work on both PyCharm & IDEA.

Later we want to extend our plugin to support other languages like c/c++ also.

How can we achieve this functionality?

In plugin.xml added optional dependencies which lets us install our plugin in both IDEA & PyCharm irrespective of the availibility of the java or python plugin.

```
<depends config-file="jetbrains-java.xml" optional="true">com.intellij.java</depends>
<depends config-file="jetbrains-python.xml" optional="true">com.intellij.modules.python</depends>
```

In build.gradle.kts, I have

```
intellij {
    version.set("2022.3.1")
    type.set("IC")
    plugins.set("com.intellij.java, PythonCore:223.8214.16")
}
```

However, hardcoding the PythonCore version, limits our plugin functionality to only the supported products listed in
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7322-python-community-edition/versions/stable/263951
But we also want to support later versions of these products like Android Studio Hedgehog.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're doing is the intended way of adding support for other languages. The `setPlugins` sets the plugins installed for the `runIde` task, it does not specify the version of the plugin that needs to be there.

So, if you `setPlugins` with a 2022.3 version of the Python plugin, it will work with the 2023 version of the Python plugin, it's just that it will be compiled with the old version.

See: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/tools-gradle-intellij-plugin.html